# People tagged with "privacy: no bulk email" seem to be receiving bulk email

Tags: civimail

It seems pretty clear that contacts tagged with "NO BULK EMAILS (USER OPT OUT)" are still receiving bulk email. I see many contacts who continue to be listed as receiving bulk emails in the mailing tab and the activities tab. We tag contacts as No Bulk Emails both internally, as well as people using the self-service link at the bottom of emails. We have been using this Civi install for many years and I feel like this feature used to work fine.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is there a setting I should check? Any helpful advice would be appreciated.

We have a standard install in Debian, Drupal 7.65, CiviCRM 5.10.3.

Comment: Do they actually receive the mail?  If they are marked as opt out and you send them a bulk mail it's clear that the mail should not be sent to them but it's less obvious how that should be recorded in the system.

Comment: That is a good question, although I would think it's pretty clear the system should not list the contact as receiving the email in the Mailing and Activities tab if they did not receive it. I can't tell if they actually received it without testing with an email I have access to, which I will do. I will update this thread after testing.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree that if they shouldn't and don't receive a bulk email, that activity shouldn't be recorded, that would be whacked. FWIW, I haven't seen this, it would be a surprising bug.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior, the no bulk mailing option is not respected and mailing activity shows under mailing tab and the email recipient replied to us that they got the email (even when they have tried to opt out multiple times).

Comment: two years later, CiviCRM 5.36.1, wordpress. members of an "all contacts" _smart group_ who opted out report about getting unwanted emails. is it possible, "smart group" is the key here?